# Moment Js loads localization too late when lazy loaded

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I tried two ways to set the locale of Moment.js. Both ways won't work, or I should say it's just too late. My "wish" is to import the locale files asynchronous (inspired [here](https://medium.com/@michalozogan/how-to-split-moment-js-locales-to-chunks-with-webpack-de9e25caccea)).

When I get to my page, the date is still in English formatted, even though it should be for example in German.

I'm loading the data asynchronously with:

```
window.moment = require('moment');
moment().format();

window.moment = require('moment-shortformat');
moment().short()

window.moment = require('moment-timezone');

const lang = document.documentElement.lang.substr(0, 2); //for the language

if(lang != 'en'){
    import(`moment/locale/${lang}.js`);
    moment.locale(lang)
}
```

Since `import(moment/locale/${lang}.js);` resolves a promise, I checked in console when the file is loaded. It's about 1 sec after the line `moment.locale(lang)` (no wonder moment is not ready to display the correct translated date).

A small sanity check shows: the locale is correctly set when I write `moment.locale()` in the console.

If I don't use lazy loading, like so:

```
import 'moment/locale/de';
moment.locale(lang);
```

Everything works fine.

My second approach is a bit longer but still had no luck. To sum it up. I created a javascript file on the backend with php with:

```
...
$file = base_path('node_modules/moment/locale/' . $locale . '.js');
...
```

so I can call dynamically the right js file. But still no luck.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Right, if it's async and it's waiting for a promise you have to chain a `then()` call. Here is the example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

```
import('/modules/my-module.js')
  .then((module) => {
    // Do something with the module.
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it that I obviously tried it in the promise. It actually does not matter if you set it there or outside. Still, I have no luck with this approach because Vue is faster loading moment is setting the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Since dynamic import returns a promise, you can call moment.locale when the promise is resolved:

```
if(lang != 'en'){
  import(`moment/locale/${lang}.js`).then(module => {
    moment.locale(lang)
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that I tried it before, but still no luck :( my Vue is just faster than the promise and that is why it's still rendered wrong